# Azure Endpoints don´t show in other VMs

Tags: azure, high-availability, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

We´ve created a number of VMs on Azure and want to group HTTP Endpoints together into a Load-Balanced set.

On the first Server, we create the set:
[image]

No matter what we do, it´s greyed out when trying to add a new Endpoint:
[image]

How would we make that work?
Also, how do those settings work together with the traffic manager we´ve created? Do they replace it? Is there a special URL for a set?

Comment: Endpoints are configured once per Cloud Service. If you've added all your VMs to the same Cloud Service you don't need to do it more than once. Some screenshots of your issue would help here.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I´ve been creating VMs and didn´t know what a "Cloud Service" is there for...

Answer (score 1):

While defining your Cloud Service you must have mentioned your endpoints. If you've spun your VMs to the same Cloud Service you the endpoints will be automatically same as defined. However just to confirm the endpoints you can use this powershell-

```
 Get-AzureVM –ServiceName "CS2961" –Name "TestServer111" | Get-AzureEndpoint
```